# Debugging fails with gdb: "Could not find the frame base", but works with lldb

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, lldb

I'm trying to debug my C++ application with gdb but when I try to print any variable "p *var*", I get the message:

> Could not find the frame base for *function name*.

However, it is possible to set a breakpoint "break *sourcefile*:15" and to step through the source code.

I compile my application on an OSX 10.9 with gcc48 4.8.3 and the compiler flags `-Wall -Wno-write-strings -std=c++11 -m64 -fopenmp -msse4.2 -O0 -g`. The gdb has the version "GNU gdb (GDB) 7.7.1".

When I use lldb for debugging, all seems to work fine.

Do you have any idea why GDB is not working?

Comment: OS X 10.9 doesn't come with gdb by default. Did you install it separately and did code signing?

Comment: @HaithamGad thanks for your comment. Yes I tried that. I compiled my own gdb and signed it. I also tried to install it with brew and signed it. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Try compiling with -gstrict-dwarf. Maybe this version of gcc is writing non-standard dwarf extensions that are not yet readable by that version of gdb.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on MacOS > 10.8 and for 2 years didn't use gdb+gcc on Mac, today I managed to solve it by adding `-gdwarf-3` option for the compiler options and it started working (gcc 6 installed using homebrew, gdb 7.11). Also Eclipse+CDT debugging now works.